# HTML email code removed by Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, email

We are facing a really strange behaviour in Chrome.

We are working with email templates.
Our template is actually a table, split into a header HTML file and a body HTML file.

The header file contains table's header,
the body contains columns for the related rows.

Requirement is to change a cell background color based on the value of another column in the row.

So we added in the body HTML file the following portion of code:

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css"> 
.sfondoY {background-color: #F00;} 
.sfondoN {background-color: #FFF;} 
</STYLE>
```

And in the cell specification we add a simple custom code (in red) to call the above style type:
([alert incidenza Flag] is the name of the column in the row containing the dynamic value to be controlled)

```
</td>   
<td class="sfondo[Alert Incidenza Flag]" style= "BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 1pt solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5.4pt; BORDER-TOP: medium none; PADDING-LEFT: 5.4pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0cm; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; WIDTH: 52.1pt; PADDING-TOP: 0cm; BORDER-BOTTOM: #4f81bd 1pt solid;   HEIGHT: 13.2pt; mso-border-bottom-themecolor: accent1; mso-border-bottom-alt: #4F81BD 1.0pt; mso-border-top-themecolor: accent1; mso-border-top-alt: #4F81BD 1.0pt; mso-border-right-alt: windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: windowtext .5pt; mso-border-style-alt: solid" valign="top" width="69";> 
  <p class="sfondo[Alert Incidenza Flag]" style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt; mso-yfti-cnfc: 64">[Incidenza Parziale]</p>
  </td>
```

The instruction seems to be correctly interpreted by the browser, because in the code source of the email we can see the following:

```
</td>   
<td class="sfondoY" style= "BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 1pt solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5.4pt; BORDER-TOP: medium none; PADDING-LEFT: 5.4pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0cm; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; WIDTH: 52.1pt; PADDING-TOP: 0cm; BORDER-BOTTOM: #4f81bd 1pt solid;   HEIGHT: 13.2pt; mso-border-bottom-themecolor: accent1; mso-border-bottom-alt: #4F81BD 1.0pt; mso-border-top-themecolor: accent1; mso-border-top-alt: #4F81BD 1.0pt; mso-border-right-alt: windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: windowtext .5pt; mso-border-style-alt: solid" valign="top" width="69";  > 
  <p class="sfondoY" style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt; mso-yfti-cnfc: 64">-14.933</p>
</td>
```

But when we open the email in Chrome, this seems to be overwritten, as the format of the email does not show.
So we saved the email on desktop as an HTML file, and we tried to open the saved file in Chrome...And... MAGICALLY THE EMAIL FORMAT APPEARS!

Is this something normal? 
Have we made mistakes in our configuration?
Please give us any possible suggestions, as we are struggling on this!